# Instagram Branding Guidelines Issue

Tags: instagram

I am trying the to create a instagram App but it's rejected everytime with Brand Name issue. Any One can provide the help..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUxTC.png)

Comment: https://en.instagram-brand.com/guidelines/general

Answer (score 0):

Look at the page they reference.

https://en.instagram-brand.com/guidelines/general

Particularly: " Don’t combine any part of the Instagram brand with a company name, trademarks or other generic terms. Instagram content shouldn’t be more than 50 percent of your design nor the most prominent feature. Avoid trademarks, names, domain names, logos or other content that could be confused with Instagram. " and " Don’t combine “Insta” or “gram” with your own brand "

We also don't know anything about your app, only the error you got.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply..

you mean to say, don't use the insta, gram in any text area ?

Comment: Don't use it in the application name primarily, don't let there be any kind of confusion with Instagram. I think you would be the safest finding alternative terms from "Insta" or "gram", throughout your application. The link referenced gives you all of their specifications to pass. They are basically trying to prevent clones of their application from plaguing the internet.